# Source Excel file and destination is flat file in the ssis with headers and footers

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

We have a source Excel file and a destination flat file in SSIS, I have created a package earlier which have OLEDB source and flat file destination by using stored procedure. I created headers and footers in the flat file, but now this time requirement has changed: we have Excel source and flatfile destination with same logic as stored procedure has.

Is there any way for I think Excel to SQL Server, and then SQL Server to CSV in data flow task?

Comment: Please, describe what you want to achieve, add sample data and desired output, and provide the exact step you cannot perform. Currently your question is unclear and hard to understand.

Comment: Unless you have a specific reason to do an intermediate step from excel to DB, you can read excel and write to flat file directly in SSIS